# Need to clear something about forwarding message on RADIUS

Tags: radius

I'm totally newbie on RADIUS, so I'm not sure if this is right or wrong.

I was been told that RADIUS packet could contain additional info that could be send to the other backward service like ERP or other internal service after successful authentication. But I searched google and I didn't found anything told me that I could "***Fetch and Forward content from RADIUS packet***".

After reading few info about RADIUS on TechNet, CISCO, and WIKI, what they said is totally different about what I was been told. Please help me to clear my thinking if my following work flow is wrong.

1. Client send authentication info to RADIUS Server.
2. After successful verification, RADIUS send accept message and HTTP-Redirect info to reach our internal service to client.
3. Once client received those messages, He/She would be able to operates our internal service.

About 2 and 3, I would like some detailed explains if RADIUS would act like port-forwarding or something after successful authentication. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the standard RADIUS protocol allows redirects of HTTP user traffic.  Some vendors may add support for this via their own [VSAs (Vendor Specific Attributes)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2865#page-47), but you will need to consult the documentation for your NAS (Network Access Server) to determine what they are, it's impossible to give generic advice as to what the attributes are or what the contents should be.

In most instances where this functionality is supported by a NAS, the VSA will be included in the Access-Accept by the RADIUS server, which will be in response to an Access-Request as you suggested in your question.

For HTTP redirection RADIUS is being used to provide parameters to configure the user's session on the NAS but does not actually perform any traffic redirection itself.

A standards-based example of this kind of dynamic configuration are the [RADIUS Attributes for Tunnel Protocol Support](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2868).  Here instead of dynamically configuring HTTP redirects, the RADIUS server can include attributes to assign users to different VLANs or to have the NAS establish tunnels on their behalf.

Comment: nice and clear. now I know what should I search. thanks